# how to use request.getparametervalues for update cart?

Tags: arrays, servlets, http-request-parameters

in my cart page i show my product using an enhance for loop and therefore all input fields have same name 
as example -

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= tcart.getIdtcart() %>" name="tcartid">
<input type="number"  class="form-control" id="cartqty" value="<%= tcart.getQty()%>" min="1" max="<%= tcart.getProduct().getQty()%>" name="cartqty">
```

this run twice if there are two products in the cart.
now my problem is when someone update the cart i send my form data into servlet in GET POST and it shows like this

```
http://localhost:8084/boodybuilding/updatecart?tcartid=98&cartqty=10&tcartid=99&cartqty=5
```

i used `getParameterValues` to get values

```
String[] id = request.getParameterValues("tcartid");
String[] qty = request.getParameterValues("cartqty");
```

but what i want to do is i want to update my cart table using first index of id array with the value of first index of qty array, second ID with the second qty, and so on.

Comment: Do you know how to use a for loop?

Comment: @balusc I'm still half asleep, I didn't even see the tags.